# Windows Powershell: Display File Path along with Name and LastWriteTime

Tags: file, powershell, path, directory

I'm using a Windows Powershell code that is very good but with one caveat. See below:

```
PS F:\Bizfi> dir -r | Out-GridView | Select FullName, LastWriteTime
```

The caveat is that it does not display the file path. Is there a way to include the file path within the name or as a separate property?

Thanks

Comment: `dir -r | Select FullName, LastWriteTime | Out-GridView`?

Comment: Thanks! I guess I just needed to switch it around a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mimic normal Get-ChildItem output:

```
dir -r | Select Mode,LastWriteTime,Length,Name,Fullname | Out-GridView
```